# Java Http Proxy does not work correctly

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I try to implement a Java Proxy for Http (Https will be the extension after Http works). I found a lot of resources on the Internet and try to solve all problems on my own so far. But now I come to a point where I stuck. 
My Proxoy does not load the full http websites. I get a lot of error messages with the socket is already closed. So I think I try to send something over a Socket that is closed.

My Problem is now. I can not see why it is like this. I think a lot over the problem but I can not find the mistake. From my side The Sockets only get closed when the server close the connection to my Proxy Server. This happen when I read a -1 on the input stream from the server.

I would be happy for any help :-)

greetings 
Christoph

```
public class ProxyThread extends Thread {
Socket client_socket;
Socket server_socket;
boolean thread_var = true;
int buffersize = 32768;

ProxyThread(Socket s) {
    client_socket = s;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Run Client Thread");
    try {
        // Read request
        final byte[] request = new byte[4096];
        byte[] response = new byte[4096];

        final InputStream in_client = client_socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out_client = client_socket.getOutputStream();

        in_client.read(request);
        System.out.println("---------------------- Request Info --------------------");
        System.out.println(new String(request));        

        Connection conn = new Connection(new String(request));
        System.out.println("---------------------- Connection Info --------------------");
        System.out.println("Host: " + conn.host);
        System.out.println("Port: " + conn.port);
        System.out.println("URL: " + conn.URL);
        System.out.println("Type: " + conn.type);
        System.out.println("Keep-Alive:" + conn.keep_alive);
        server_socket = new Socket(conn.URL, conn.port);
        InputStream in_server = server_socket.getInputStream();
        final OutputStream out_server = server_socket.getOutputStream();
        out_server.write(request);
        out_server.flush();

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
              int bytes_read;
              try {
                while ((bytes_read = in_client.read(request)) != -1) {
                      out_server.write(request, 0, bytes_read);
                      out_server.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
          };
          t.start();

        int bytes_read;
        while ((bytes_read = in_server.read(response)) != -1) {
            out_client.write(response, 0, bytes_read);
            out_client.flush();
            //System.out.println("---------------------- Respone Info --------------------");
            //System.out.println(new String(response));
        }

        //System.out.println("EIGENTLICH FERTIG");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client_socket.close();
            server_socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: 
My HTTP Proxy now works. The Answer is pretty helpfull once you understand what is ryl going on. If you come hear to find a solution this questions may help you:

- Does the client send a request only to one Website / Webserver? Means do we always have the same port / hostname?
- The Loop from the answer is very usefull but think where to place it?

Last think: Thanks @EJP its working your reply was very usefull. It only tooks a time to understand it!

Comment: Can you check: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html. It can help!

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy I don't know why you're digging up a 20-year-old magazine article when there is a perfectly good networking tutorial supplied by Oracle.

Comment: So the old article is wrong! I would say age of the article doesn't matter when it solves your problem. At least it can give an idea on how things were done. what say! @EJP

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy I agree that truth is not a function of time, but (a) it doesn't solve any problem here and (b) it is not a primary source.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. I would let the author decide

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy If the author was capable of making that decision he wouldn't be posting here. He's the one with the problem. Our task is to help him in the most efficient way we can, and that is done by posting *relevant* remarks or resources, and confining ourselves to primary resources rather than arbitrary Internet junk, which ultimately has no more status than this site: probably less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making all the usual mistakes, and a few more.

1. The entire request is not guaranteed to arrive in a single read. You can't assume more than a single byte has arrived. You have to loop.
2. You aren't checking for end of stream at this stage.
3. You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 to implement HTTP, specifically the parts about Content-length and transfer encoding.
4. You cannot assume that the server will close the connection after sending the response.
5. Closing either the input or the output stream or a socket closes the socket. This is the reason for your `SocketException: socket closed`.
6. When you get to HTTPS you will need to look at the CONNECT verb.
7. Flushing a socket output stream does nothing, and flushing inside a loop is to be avoided,

Comment: to 1: I thought I do this with the while loops?
to 2: I thought I would do the check with -1? 
to 4: I thought I close everythign with Finaly at the end?

Comment: 1,2. You are constructing a `Connection` object with a string built incorrectly from the first read, ignoring both the actual length and the possibility of a premature end of stream, and which could consist of as little as one byte. 4. You are getting a 'socket closed' exception, which means you are doing a *premature* socket close, and I am telling you why.

Comment: I think I do not understand what the read of -1 means. I thought if  inputstream.read() = -1 then the server closed the connection to us. So no messages will arrive on this socket. and i can close everything.

to 1,2, I have to find out the hostname and the port to open a socket. If i can not do it this way. What would be the correct way?

Comment: That is exactly what -1 means. I do not understand why you're even asking. You need to look at, or post here, the stack trace of your 'socket closed' exception to understand where the premature close is. But it's there, somewhere. That is the meaning of the exception. You closed the socket and then continued to use it.